# C# zero out jagged array

Tags: c#, zero, jagged-arrays

I frequently make use of jagged arrays in my programming.  Often, they'll be static in size, but I'll be re-filling them with new data.  In the past, I've just made use of the 'new' operator to wipe out the array, and then just re-initialise it.  However, I suspect that it's probably not best practice.
Any advice on the best method to clear a jagged array out and zero all its values?

I'm familiar with Array.Clear, but as far as I'm aware, because Jagged arrays aren't technically contiguous, I believe I have to loop and clear each child individually?
Thanks in advance!
Jaspar

Comment: One of the reasons to use C# is so you don't have to worry about this. Just create new ones - C# cleans up for you (by design).

Comment: "In the past, I've just made use of the 'new' operator to wipe out the array, and then just re-initialise it. However, I suspect that it's probably not best practice." Why? What makes you think clearing the array is a better practice then instantiate a new array on the same reference? (I'm not saying you are wrong or right, I've never bothered to check it myself, I'm just curious as to your reasoning).

Comment: Like I say, I've always just created new in the past.  However, I suspect that there's a certain amount of overhead in allocating the memory each time the new operator is called, and also presumably makes the garbage collector work harder.  That said, I don't know how it compares to the overhead of running the Clear operator.  I'm mostly working with fairly large 3D arrays for image processing, so performance is definitely a consideration when I'm approaching anything to do with array manipulation!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'm not sure if the overhead of allocating memory and garbage collection is larger then clearing the 3d jagged array (which requires at least nested loops + array.Clear). You might want to [race these horses.](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Answer (score 1):

I would use [`Array.Clear()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.clear(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
int[][] jagged = new int[][] {
    new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 },
    new int[] { 11, 12 },
    new int[] { 21, 22, 23 }
};

for (int i = 0; i < jagged.Length; i++)
{
    Array.Clear(jagged[i], 0, jagged[i].Length);
}
```

instead of

```
for (int i = 0; i < jagged.Length; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < jagged[i].Length; j++)
    {
        jagged[i][j] = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @fubo , that's what I suspected, just wanted to confirm, as I could find any articles specifically on clearing jagged arrays.  I'm mostly working with 3 dimentional arrays, which can be quite a lot of calls to the Clear method, so just wanted to check there wasn't a single method I could apply at the top that would cascade down.

Comment: I get the impression that c# is more optimised for jagged arrays than multi-dimensional arrays.  However, if I want to do this kind of clearing repeatedly, am I better off doing a multi-dimentional array, so I can run one clear with the total length?  Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I believe that you will have to loop on the sub array.

A jagged array is an array of array. The `default( refenence type )` is a null reference. So a Clear jagged array will be here an array of null references.

But you want each member of those array to be cleared so :

```
foreach (int[] subArray in jaggedArr)
{
    Array.Clear (subArray, 0, subArray.Length);
}
```

Comment: Clearing the fact that a Cleared Jagged is an array of null seems like a clarification that needed to be.

Comment: @PatrickHofman But not even a char from Fubo was copy pasted here. But I could make it more clear.

Comment: @PatrickHofman, I can Skeet the answer if you still feel it does not have it's own personality. basic step are One line sort answer in bold then the answer for this specifc case with related link to MSDN and C# source. Then a generic implementation. Btw my English is bad this is not sarcasm, m dead serious. And I personnally find foreach more readable especialy when multiple jagged array were jagged together.

Answer (score 0):

It is enough to remove all existing references by assigning null to make array ready for Garbage Collection.   `(array=null)`

Then it is possible to force garbage collection by calling `(array.Collect())`,

Comment: If you create a large array, and you intend to reuse it, memory wise it is better to clear out the existing one than dropping it and creating a whole new memory segment.

Comment: @PatrickHofman How about the execution of parallel programs on shared-memory? This solution can be useful depends on a situation.